# Return element showing the error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am getting a compilation error at the return type element ,
the error is that not all the code path returns a value.

I am returning the integer value. Where did I make a mistake? My
code following

```
 public int InsertUserData(UserDetail userDetail, BusinessObjects objects,PersonalData newPersonal,EducationalData newEducational,ContactData newContact)
    {
        try
        {
            UserCredential objCredentials;
            int result=1;
            if (objects.Status==1)
            {
                 objCredentials = newPersonEntity.UserCredentials
                                                 .First(cd => cd.UserName == objects.UserName);
                objCredentials.Status = objects.Status;
                newPersonEntity.UserDetails.Add(userDetail);
                 result = newPersonEntity.SaveChanges();
                return result;
            }
            else if (objects.Status == 2)
            {
                switch (objects.FormId)
                {
                    case 1:
                             objCredentials = newPersonEntity.UserCredentials
                                             .First(cd => cd.UserName == objects.UserName);
                            objCredentials.Status = objects.Status;
                            newPersonEntity.PersonalDatas.Add(newPersonal);
                            result = newPersonEntity.SaveChanges();
                            break;
                    case 2:
                             objCredentials = newPersonEntity.UserCredentials
                                             .First(cd => cd.UserName == objects.UserName);
                            objCredentials.Status = objects.Status;
                            newPersonEntity.EducationalDatas.Add(newEducational);
                            result = newPersonEntity.SaveChanges();
                            break;
                    case 3: 
                             objCredentials = newPersonEntity.UserCredentials
                                             .First(cd => cd.UserName == objects.UserName);
                            objCredentials.Status = objects.Status;
                            newPersonEntity.ContactDatas.Add(newContact);
                            result = newPersonEntity.SaveChanges();
                            break;

                   default:
                            break;
                }

               return result;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {  
            CatchError(ex);
            return 3;
        }


    }
```

Can anyone tell me what mistake I made in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning value if `objects.Status==1` and `objects.Status==2` but nothing if objects.Status has other value. So I would recommend you to return default value like

```
else
{
   return 0; // or any other value
}
```

and your new code will be

```
public int InsertUserData(UserDetail userDetail, BusinessObjects objects,PersonalData newPersonal,EducationalData newEducational,ContactData newContact)
    {
        try
        {
            UserCredential objCredentials;
            int result=1;
            if (objects.Status==1)
            {
                 objCredentials = newPersonEntity.UserCredentials
                                                 .First(cd => cd.UserName == objects.UserName);
                objCredentials.Status = objects.Status;
                newPersonEntity.UserDetails.Add(userDetail);
                 result = newPersonEntity.SaveChanges();
                return result;
            }
            else if (objects.Status == 2)
            {
                switch (objects.FormId)
                {
                    case 1:
                             objCredentials = newPersonEntity.UserCredentials
                                             .First(cd => cd.UserName == objects.UserName);
                            objCredentials.Status = objects.Status;
                            newPersonEntity.PersonalDatas.Add(newPersonal);
                            result = newPersonEntity.SaveChanges();
                            break;
                    case 2:
                             objCredentials = newPersonEntity.UserCredentials
                                             .First(cd => cd.UserName == objects.UserName);
                            objCredentials.Status = objects.Status;
                            newPersonEntity.EducationalDatas.Add(newEducational);
                            result = newPersonEntity.SaveChanges();
                            break;
                    case 3: 
                             objCredentials = newPersonEntity.UserCredentials
                                             .First(cd => cd.UserName == objects.UserName);
                            objCredentials.Status = objects.Status;
                            newPersonEntity.ContactDatas.Add(newContact);
                            result = newPersonEntity.SaveChanges();
                            break;

                   default:
                            break;
                }

               return result;
            }
            else
            {
              return 0; // or any other value
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {  
            CatchError(ex);
            return 3;
        }


    }
```